# Receiving an str/int error and can't understand why

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling

I'm currently trying to find the complementary strand of DNA, meaning I have to replace all Ts with As, As with Ts, Cs with Gs, and Gs with Cs. I have been trying to find a way to do this that doesn't result in the program returning entirely one letter and I think I found the way but now every time I run it I receive an error telling me to convert a line to str and I can't place where it should be or why, here's the code I have currently:

```
#open file with DNA strand
df = open('dnafile.txt','r')

#function for finding complementary strand
def encode(code,DNA):
    for k in code:
        DNA = DNA.replace(k,code[k])
    print('The complementary strand is: ' + DNA)

#carrying out function
code = {ord('A'):'T', ord('T'):'A', ord('G'):'C', ord('C'):'G'}
DNA = df.read()
encode(code,DNA)
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`biopython`](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython)? After creating a Sequence with an assigned Alphabet, just use the [`reverse_complement()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc23) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in *integers* as the first argument to `DNA.replace()` where it only takes *strings*; `ord('A')` produces an integer, and that's what you pass in as `k`:

```
DNA = DNA.replace(k, code[k])
```

You could replace `ord('A')` with just `'A'` but then you have *new* issues, namely that the `C->G` replacement is going to be undone by the `G->C` replacement or vice versa.

You should instead use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), and remove the loop:

```
def encode(code,DNA):
    DNA = DNA.translate(code)
    print('The complementary strand is: ' + DNA)
```

Also see [Simultaneous .replace functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322898/simultaneous-replace-functionality) (which was linked to as a duplicate from your previous question, and it appears you only *partly* implemented my approach there).